# Probability of student passing an exam

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

There're $25$ tests, each with $2$ questions. There're total of $50$ different questions (the questions do not repeat). The student knows the answer of $44$ questions. To pass the exam, the student needs to correctly answer both questions on the first test he drew, or answer $1$ question from the test he drew first, and $1$ question from the test he drew second. (meaning he draws twice if he answers a question incorrectly on his first try)

What is the probability that the student will pass the exam?

I have never faced a problem like this one so any help is appreciated. I was thinking about approaching it "manually" with some applied combinatorics but I feel like there's a much easier way that I am not familiar with.

Comment: What do you mean by "manually"? You should still provide your thoughts because basically counting "the right way" is the easiest, I think.

Comment: @Max I was thinking about finding out the probability that the student draws a sheet that has 2 questions he does not know the answer to, but then I'd get stuck with the second part.

Comment: Presumably if he gets a question that he doesn't know the answer to he is guaranteed to get the question wrong (*e.g. the questions are short answer, not multiple choice*).  Without information as to how the questions are organized, I think it would be a fair assumption to assume that the test he receives has two questions taken **independently and uniformly at random without replacement** (*without this assumption there is not enough information: e.g. he knows answers to questions 1-44 but not 45-50 and tests have questions 2k-1 and 2k has different odds*).  Similarly for second test.

Comment: Consider then a rephrasing of the question:  You have an urn with 50 balls.  Each of them are labeled with different numbers and are colored either red or blue.  There are $44$ red balls and $6$ blue balls.  A player comes and draws two balls without replacement.  If both are red he wins. If one is red and one is blue, then he draws an additional two more balls. If at least one is red then he wins. Find the probability of winning.  What is the probability he wins during the first draw? What is the probability he doesn't win during first draw but gets a second chance? Wins during second chance?

Comment: @JMoravitz you're a genious :)

Comment: @JMoravitz so the probability he wins during the first try is 0.77 (44/50 * 43/50), the probability that he gets a second chance is 0.012(6/50 * 5/49)
Now the probability during the second chance would depend on the outcome of the first draw and how do I compute this probability? Bayes?

Comment: Actually I've made a mistake. I can't compute the probability of getting a second chance this way so I'm confused again :/

Comment: @Hydroxis: The outcomes are $\rm (RR,XX)$ or $\rm (RB, RX)$ which are disjoint.  So it's the probability of "two red first try", or "exactly one red first and then at least one red second try."   edit: and see JMoravitz's answer just posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throughout all of this explanation, the key fact/property that we use is the multiplication principle of probability:

> $Pr(E\cap F) = Pr(E)\cdot Pr(F\mid E)$

Using the interpretation of the problem given in the comments above relating the problem to taking balls from an urn with 44 red and 6 blue balls:

Let $A_{r,r}$ stand for the event where you draw two reds during the first two balls.  $A_{r,b}$ stand for the event where you draw one red and one blue during the first two balls *in either the order red,blue or in the order blue,red*.  Similarly, let $B_{r,r}$ and $B_{r,b}$ stand for the same events but for the second round of pulling.

$Pr(win) =Pr(A_{r,r}\cup (A_{r,b}\cap B_{r,r})\cup (A_{r,b}\cap B_{r,b}))$

$= Pr(A_{r,r})+Pr(A_{r,b})\cdot Pr(B_{r,r}\mid A_{r,b})+Pr(A_{r,b})\cdot Pr(B_{r,b}\mid A_{r,b})$

We could split the above via addition as they are mutually exclusive events.  We then simplified the intersections via multiplication principle.  We continue and calculate each of the terms above:

> We have the following: $Pr(A_{r,r}) = \binom{44}{2}/\binom{50}{2} = \frac{44}{50}\cdot \frac{43}{49}$, $Pr(A_{r,b}) = \binom{44}{1}\binom{6}{1}/\binom{50}{2} = 2\cdot\frac{44}{50}\cdot\frac{6}{49}$, $Pr(B_{r,r}\mid A_{r,b}) = \binom{43}{2}/\binom{48}{2} =\frac{43}{48}\cdot\frac{42}{47}$ etc...

For a specific explanation on how to calculate $Pr(B_{r,b}\mid A_{r,b})$, we may temporarily assume that each ball has been labeled and that each ball is equally likely to be drawn.

Given that $A_{r,b}$ has occurred, there are 43 red balls and 5 blue balls left for a total of 48 balls remaining.  For $B_{r,b}$ to occur in this scenario then, the red ball drawn must be one of those remaining 43 red balls and the blue ball drawn must be one of those 5 blue balls.  There are $\binom{48}{2}$ equally likely ways to draw two balls and $\binom{43}{1}\binom{5}{1}$ ways in which you can draw one red and one blue ball simultaneously where order doesn't matter.  Thus $Pr(B_{r,b}\mid A_{r,b}) = \binom{43}{1}\binom{5}{1}/\binom{48}{2}$

Phrased differently, allowing order in which the two balls are drawn to matter, it can either be red then blue or blue then red.  If red then blue, the probability of drawing a red ball in this scenario is $\frac{43}{48}$.  Following this occurring, the probability of then drawing a blue ball is $\frac{5}{47}$.  If blue then red the probability of drawing a blue and then a red is $\frac{5}{48}$ and $\frac{43}{47}$ respectively.  Applying multiplication principle and adding we get then $Pr(B_{r,b}\mid A_{r,b}) = \frac{43}{48}\cdot\frac{5}{47} + \frac{5}{48}\cdot\frac{43}{47}$ which after calculation one will see is equivalent to the answer found previously.